# Google maps api get lat and lng dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I run my code, the map doesn't display. I am working on my localhost. I want to put lat and lng to inputs. Then when I change the lat and lng the inputs will change dynamically. How can I solve this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
Lat: <input type="text" id="lat"><br>
Lng: <input type="text" id="lng">
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41,28);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 15, 
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), myOptions);
    addMarker(myLatlng, 'Default Marker', map);
    map.addListener('click',function(event) {
        addMarker(event.latLng, 'Click Generated Marker', map);
    );
}}
function addMarker(latlng,title,map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: title,
            draggable:true
    });
    marker.addListener('drag',function(event) {
        $('#lat').val() = event.latLng.lat();
        $('#lng').val() = event.latLng.lng();
    });
    marker.addListener('dragend',function(event) {
        $('#lat').val() = event.latLng.lat();
        $('#lng').val() = event.latLng.lng();
    });}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Please describe the issue better. The map doesn't show? The inputs don't get updated? What is the problem? Any error in your javascript console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You have some bugs in your code.. and you are not calling the function
>   `initialize()`. Try this updated code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
Lat: <input type="text" id="lat"><br>
Lng: <input type="text" id="lng">
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41,28);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 15, 
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), myOptions);
    addMarker(myLatlng, 'Default Marker', map);
    map.addListener('click',function(event) {
        addMarker(event.latLng, 'Click Generated Marker', map);
    });
}
function addMarker(latlng,title,map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: title,
            draggable:true
    });
    marker.addListener('drag',function(event) {
         $('#lat').val(event.latLng.lat())  ;
        $('#lng').val(event.latLng.lng())  ;
    });
    marker.addListener('dragend',function(event) {
        $('#lat').val(event.latLng.lat())  ;
        $('#lng').val(event.latLng.lng())  ;
    });
}
initialize();
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Also I have an another question. How can I save selected coordinates. For example I move the marker a coordinate. I want to save in array or a div. İnfact I want to do visit history.

Comment: Add a global array variable and push `event.latLng.lat() & event.latLng.lng()` to that array  inside 'dragend' event.

Answer (score 2):

Here I can save selected coordinates. İt may help someone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
Lat: <input type="text" id="lat"><br>
Lng: <input type="text" id="lng">
<p id="results">result</p>
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.015137,28.979530);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 10, 
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), myOptions);
    addMarker(myLatlng, 'Default Marker', map);
    map.addListener('click',function(event) {
        addMarker(event.latLng, 'Click Generated Marker', map);
    });
}
function addMarker(latlng,title,map) {
    var coords = [];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: title,
            draggable:true
    });
    marker.addListener('drag',function(event) {
         $('#lat').val(event.latLng.lat())  ;
        $('#lng').val(event.latLng.lng())  ;

    });
    marker.addListener('dragend',function(event) {
        $('#lat').val(event.latLng.lat())  ;
        $('#lng').val(event.latLng.lng())  ;
        coords.push(event.latLng.lat());
        coords.push(event.latLng.lng());
        $("#results").append('<div>'+JSON.stringify(coords)+'</div>');
        coords = [];
    });
}
initialize();
</script>
</body></html>
```